# How can I keep the value of a checkbox with a page refresh on JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to keep the checkbox status after a page refresh.
Example: I check the checkbox and it remains checked after the page refresh in jquery.
Here is my source code:

HTML :

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name ="check" class="checkbox" id="actif" data-articles="${obj.articles}" value="${obj.actif}">
</td>
```

[pictures of checkelements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ4jK.png)

JQUERY :

```
       let isChecked = localStorage.getItem("checkedbox");
          $('#check').prop('checked', isChecked)
        });

        $('#check').on('click', function() {
            localStorage.setItem("checkedbox", $(this).prop('checked'));
            $('form').submit();
        })
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing ?

Comment: @brk : I have no error, but it doesn't work when I refresh

Comment: @AnJa Are you sure about the ID of the input? The HTML code has ID "actif" but the JS has something else.

Comment: @K K , I changed the ID but no change